# How to bypass user acknowledge (OAuth 2.0) for Google Calendar API usage?

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, user-experience

I want to be able to make some basic Google Calendar integrations using the respective calendar API. Is there a way to achieve this (from a javascript side or from an ASP.NET or Node.js side) WITHOUT having the front-end user confirm on the acknowledgement screen (part of OAuth 2.0) auth process?

PS - I'm trying to provide the best user experience for my customers using my web app (ASP.NET React JS app). I have multiple services (e.g. Google Calendar, DropBox, and another 3rd party email provider) which I'm trying to tie altogether into a seamless UX.

Thanks.

Comment: I hope not, if that was possible, it'd be a security risk

Comment: I know it is a security risk. But I know Google Workspace docs talk about a service account which can be used to avoid the user acknowledging screen. Plus, im sure there are other apps out there that has solved this "problem". Again, the goal being a seamless UX. https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/auth-overview

Comment: Are you a google workspace administrator for the domain your users are on?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because user consent is a step required by the OAuth protocol

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).